# How to define a custom user defined command to filter a range?

Tags: external-command, user-commands

I want to select some lines in visual mode, and enter a custom command `:Ex<CR>` so that:

```
'<,'>!expand -t4
```

is run to expand all tabs in selected range. How to define  the `Ex` command?

I have tried things like:

```
command! -range Ex !expand -t4
```

but that command just hangs, it seems that the range was not forwarded.

Answer (score 7):

Ranges are not forwarded automatically, you need to use `<line1>` and `<line2>` for that:

```
command! -range Ex <line1>,<line2>!expand -t4
```

You should read the manuals of `:help :command` about `-range` and `<line1>`. Basically:

- if `Ex` is called with a range, `<line1>` and `<line2>` expand to that range
- otherwise, the default value of range is used. Without any default specified, `<line1>` and `<line2>` both expand to the current line.

  You could also use: `-range=%` to act on the entire file by default.